# Geospatial support in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, geospatial, postgis

How would I map point and polygon to java types. If this is not possible, what is a workaround?

I would like to use geospatial support in mysql or postgres through JPA.

Comment: I'm considering forking hibernate spatial and create some basic generic JPA 2.1 geospatial support library. Something like `JPA spatial`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this too - you can get the data if you declare your field in JPA as a `Byte[]` and it will come down as a blob, but in MySQL spatial internal format - so no matter what, you'll always get an unreadable internal format - your best bet in JPA is to use a native SQL query to get the data down as text.

```
SELECT AsText(columnName) FROM tableName;
```

For instace:

```
String sql = "SELECT AsText(LOCATION) FROM ENTITY where id=?1";
return (String) em.createNativeQuery(sql)
                  .setParameter(1, id)
                  .getSingleResult();
```

returns in my case: `POINT(40.01999 -75.147171)`.